# How to write GCS Parquet data to BigQuery (batch processing)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, parquet

#### What we want to solve

Writing Parquet type data stored in GCP's CloudStorage to BigQuery tables once daily (batch processing).

I am having trouble with this implementation.

#### Problem

Until now, we have been storing the following CSV in GCS and running a job to write it to BigQuery using dataflow **"Text Files on Cloud Storage to BigQuery "** template.

| Date | Company | Tel | Address | Staff | Lank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | ABC Corporation | 00−0000−0000 | US | mike | 0 |
| 2022-04-04 | DEF Corporation | 00−0000−0000 | JA | suzuki | 1 |
| 2022-04-04 | DEF Corporation | 00−0000−0000 | UK | john | 1 |
| ・ |  |  |  |  |  |
| ・ |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-06-30 | XYZ Corporation | 00−0000−0000 | UK | tom | 1 |

About 1000 rows of data in total

```
Schema for each column
Date:Datetime, 
Company:Str, 
Tel:Str, 
Address:Str, 
Staff:Str, 
Lank:Int
```

#### Future changes

Save to GCS in Parquet instead of CSV (cannot use the above template)
Write BigQuery from GCS to BigQuery once a day as a batch process.

#### What we want to implement

Batch processing to write Parquet type data in GCS to BigQuery table once a day.

Due to the above changes, we were unable to use our existing template, and were also troubled by the lack of other templates that we could use.

I would appreciate it if you could provide me with a GCP service (I was thinking of dataflow at the moment) that would be suitable for this job and a specific implementation method for implementing it.Thank you.

The languages used are either python or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Dataflow, there isn't a `Cloud Storage Parquet to BigQuery` [google-provided template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates) available.
You can file a feature request from this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=0) on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for the creation of such a template. I've checked from [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559728) that there isn't an existing FR about it as of today.

If you want to write a Dataflow/Beam pipeline on your own, the closest examples you can refer to are `Cloud Storage Parquet to Bigtable` and `Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery` from [google-provided templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates) (the source code is in Java), you have to use the Apache Beam Python SDK to write a pipeline to do it.

Or if you follow this BigQuery document [Loading Parquet data from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#python), there is this code snippet that does this job without using Dataflow:

```py
import io

from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
)

body = io.BytesIO(b"Washington,WA")
client.load_table_from_file(body, table_id, job_config=job_config).result()
previous_rows = client.get_table(table_id).num_rows
assert previous_rows > 0

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET,
)

uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.parquet"
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```